# What's wrong with my php register code?

Tags: php, forms

**i was making a register page that connects to a mysql database over include.
When i tryed to apply some rules**(no empty email,username or password) something went wrong...

When i run the script, **it just gave me HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error):**
 I have pasted the script below... 
[I am sorry for my bad coding skills...i am new to this!]

```
if ($submit) {
$check = empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email']))
if ($check == true) {
echo "Fill all the info!";
}
else {
$check1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE login='".$username."'"));

if ($check1 == 0) {

$password = base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( utf8_encode( $password))));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$lastactive."', '0', '".$IP."', '1', '".$email."')");

echo "<b><font color='gray'>You have been registered. Visit the login page in order to login and edit your account.</b>";
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The (lack of) "coding skills" is no excuse to not have enabled error reporting and looking in the error log.

Answer (score 1):

Few errors I have spotted I believe.

$check = empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email']) **)** <-- This is not needed

There is an extra ) at the end, also, there is no ; to finish the line.

Also no closed if statement at the end

```
if ($check1 == 0) {

$password = base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( utf8_encode( $password))));
```

**}** <-- This is needed

Comment: Ok so... the missing ; was the problem... Thanks alot Joe!

Comment: No problem, let me know if it all works! Have fun learning php! (im guessing your starting to learn it now?)

Answer (score 0):

You have not close ) in second line, 
and have not closed } other lines

thats for beginning.